# Determining which shape is being hovered over - Java

Tags: java, swing, hover, paint, highlight

So I have 3 rectangles drawn on my JPanel that are acting as buttons, and what I would like to do is when the mouse is hovered over one of them, the Jpanel will repaint, and change the color of only that rectangle to red.

The only way I can think to do it is to have 3 separate variables that determines if the mouse is over each component. Then there would be code in the repaint method that, if rect1hover is true, then draw using g.setColor to red.

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       if(rect1.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())){
           rect1hover = true;
       }
}
```

But this seems really inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Put your drawn rectangles in a `List`.  Then you can write this code.

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    for (DrawnRectangle r : rectangles) {
       if (r.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())){
           r.setHoverBackground();
       }
    }
}
```

You'll have to create a `DrawnRectangle` class with a `setHoverBackground` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use real components, then just add a MouseListener to each component and you don't need to do any lookup or do custom painting.

See [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more information.